# EditText Hint Doesn't Go Away

Tags: android, android-listview

Question: On devices which can handle my two-pane `Fragment` container two display a listview and the selected view side to side, `EditView android:hint` hides when text is typed in. However, on a Motorola XOOM and Nexus 7, `android:hint` doesn't go away when text is inserted.

UPDATE: I've figured out the `ListView` resizing activity problem. Because of redrawing, it only APPEARED that the `ListView` didn't resize. However, my issue with the `EditText` not hiding the `android:hint` still exists. I've added an update image of my issue now along with updated code below. I will keep the old stuff for records purposes unless other people see it fit to remove.:

[image: Updated Photo]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/contact_detail_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/chat_camera_button"
            style="android:selectableItemBackground"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:src="@drawable/camera_button" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/chat_text_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/chat_record_button"
            android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:src="@drawable/send_text_button" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/chat_record_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:longClickable="true"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/mic_disabled" />

       <EditText
           android:id="@+id/chat_message_text"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
           android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/chat_text_button"
           android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/chat_camera_button"
           android:ems="10"
           android:hint="@string/message_hint"
           android:inputType="textMultiLine|textCapSentences"
           android:maxLines="3"
           android:minLines="1" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/messages_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/chat_message_text"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:stackFromBottom="true"
            android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

UPDATE [OLD]: This appears to be local to only the Droid RAZRs I'm testing at home.. I've tested 3. Is anyone else having issues on a Droid RAZR?

I'm trying to get my List-view and Edit-text to re-size as the user enters more lines (up to 3). However, for some reason, the hint isn't going away and the List-view doesn't re-size.

Also, the android:hint used in my Edit-text does not go away when text is inside.

Here's an example of the error image
(ignore the send button, I no longer re-size it)

IMAGE FOR THOSE WHO WANT IT: https://i.stack.imgur.com/e7FJJ.png

```
Black - ListView

White - EditText + Button

Green - Text inside EditText
```

The following is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/contact_detail_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/details_record_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:text="Send" />

       <EditText
           android:id="@+id/chat_message_input"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
           android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
           android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/details_record_button"
           android:ems="10"
           android:hint="@string/message_hint"
           android:paddingRight="10dp"
           android:paddingTop="10dp"
           android:inputType="textMultiLine"
           android:minLines="1"
           android:maxLines="3"
           android:textColor="#00FF00"/>

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/messages_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/chat_message_input"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="#000000" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Have you tried making your ListView height "wrap_content"?

Comment: Yes, I've tried that as well.

Comment: its working fine for me.do u have tested it on device ?

Comment: I am testing this on a Droid RAZR. Also, does it matter if the Activity is inside a FragmentActivity?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my case, this happened because I had inflated multiple layers of the same layout. For example, I was doing this in my activity's `onCreate`:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
```

While also doing this in my fragment:

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_login, container, false);
...
return view;
```

This creates 2 controls which are perfectly overlaid. So when you are typing the text in the `EditText` control, you only type it into one of the controls. So one of them shows the text you typed, while the other one, being empty and not focused, correctly shows the hint.

The solution is therefore to remove the layout from either the activity or **all** the fragments.

Answer (score 1):

Add a TextWatcher to your editText and then when you see the text is not equal to "" set the hint text to ""

```
et1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            // MAKE CHANGES TO YOUR EDITTEXT HINT TEXT HERE
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

It's just that multiple iterations of installing APK and starting the app would have resulted in this issue. Uninstall the APP in emulator or device, it should resolve the issue.

You can try to press back button and relaunch the app, to make sure you don't have multiple instance of fragment.